# C# jQuery Ajax Post Getting Blocked by IIS Rewrite Rule

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mod-rewrite

Our domain on the product server has a couple of url rewrites which I think are preventing the jQuery from posting.

I have tried the same script on a domain same server which has no rewrite rules and the script works.

The full script I'm testing is this
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx

I just can't get my head around how to solve it. I think the rewrite rule causing the issues is the one which creates endless urls which removes the ".aspx" extension from the page name

this is the function

```
    function GetRecords() {
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CS.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried removing the .aspx in the code above but didn't make any change

The rewrite rules to remove the ".aspx" is this

```
    <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

The rewrite rules to remove the "&"

```
    <rule name="Rewrite URL to remove &amp; from path." stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)\:\[20\](.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

The rewrite rules to remove the "80"

```
    <rule name="Rewrite URL to remove [80] from path." stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)\:\[80\](.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

I'm not 100% on why the last 2 rules are in place it must be historic as this is a very old site.

The web config rewrite rules are the only differences between the 2 domains I've tested. Obviously I need to keep the rewrite rules in place and hope someone can help me solve this.

Also if I load the following in the browser

domain.com/CS.aspx/GetCustomers

the page does load

if I load

domain.com/CS/GetCustomers

I get a 404 error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could kick myself

I was calling http instead of https for

http://ajax.googleapis.com

and it was getting blocked